# Is there any way to mitigate against a compromised CA as a client on Firefox?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, firefox

If I, as a client, connect to a server and there is a malicious certificate authority, how can the client protect against this CA and still connect to the site? If this isn't possible, how can the client be aware of a compromised CA on Firefox?

Comment: Mitigate what against whom?

Comment: Assuming the site is trustworthy, but the CA is compromised, how do i connect to the server securely? (Hope this clears it up)

Comment: Visiting a (non-static) site with a bad CA is in theory insecure. Your cookies will be sent over bad https and also the unencrypted text, but in case of a static page the risk is immediately decreased because attackers are nothing with this. It is still not safe to visit a non-valid HTTPS site. A client can be aware of a non-valid CA with the firefox addon "CheckMyHTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Mitigating Effects of Malicious/Compromised Certificate Authorities

There aren't very many things you can do yourself as the client, but I will outline several solutions available anyway.

### Remove Untrusted Certificates

If there are CAs that are trusted by your browser and/or operating system that you do not personally trust, you should remove them. This is easier said than done, as there are many you cannot remove without breaking a significant number of websites. That said, there may be some you can definitely remove without harm, such as foreign governments and others that aren't commonly used. This can take some trial and error.

### HTTP Public Key Pinning (HPKP)

From [Mozilla Developer Network Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Public_Key_Pinning):

> HTTP Public Key Pinning (HPKP) is a security feature that tells a web
> client to associate a specific cryptographic public key with a certain
> web server to decrease the risk of MITM attacks with forged
> certificates.
>
> To ensure the authenticity of a server's public key used in TLS
> sessions, this public key is wrapped into a X.509 certificate which is
> usually signed by a certificate authority (CA). Web clients such as
> browsers trust a lot of these CAs, which can all create certificates
> for arbitrary domain names. If an attacker is able to compromise a
> single CA, they can perform MITM attacks on various TLS connections.
> HPKP can circumvent this threat for the HTTPS protocol by telling the
> client which public key belongs to a certain web server.
>
> HPKP is a Trust on First Use (TOFU) technique. The first time a web
> server tells a client via a special HTTP header which public keys
> belong to it, the client stores this information for a given period of
> time. When the client visits the server again, it expects at least one
> certificate in the certificate chain to contain a public key whose
> fingerprint is already known via HPKP. If the server delivers an
> unknown public key, the client should present a warning to the user.

So, if a certificate is presented to the client that doesn't match the pinned public key, or doesn't match the pinned CA's public key, the connection should fail. While there are some clear benefits to HPKP, Google and other initial supporters [now recommend against it](https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2016/09/06/is-http-public-key-pinning-dead) due to the possibility of long-term denial-of-service or hostile takeover.

### DNS-Based Authentication of Named Entities ([DANE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6698))

DANE doesn't rely on CAs at all, and can operate independent of/without them. A DNS query over DNSSEC for a domain's TLSA returns information about what certificates should be treated as valid. I am unsure how widely DANE is deployed, but it could possibly be enabled through a browser addon.

## Detecting Compromised CAs

If a CA itself doesn't know it's been compromised, there is really no way you would be able to determine that yourself. The only way I can imagine to catch a newly-compromised/malicious CA is if you knew CA "A" is usually in the chain for a domain, but you observe CA "B" in the chain instead. I imagine that a browser extension could keep track of this information and alert the user to any changes, but I fear that false positives would be indistinguishable from malicious events.

Comment: (1) the preload list supports key pins, at least for now (2) even if your resolver(s) and someone's server hierarchy all support DNSSEC _and_ DANE, registrar data gets compromised more often than CAs (3) if you do trust DNS, you could also check CAA _if_ the site uses it _and_ leaves it after issuance which is not required